# Why gnustep-config outputs nothing for any parameter?

Tags: ubuntu, gnu, gnustep

Regardless of what I run:

```
gnustep-config --debug-flags
gnustep-config --objc-flags
gnustep-config --base-libs
```

It outputs nothing. How would I debug this?

PS: the OS details: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, gnustep-make-2.6.1-1

PPS:

```
zerkms@ubuntu-1204-2-server-amd64:~$ . /usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh
zerkms@ubuntu-1204-2-server-amd64:~$ gnustep-config --debug-flags
zerkms@ubuntu-1204-2-server-amd64:~$ gnustep-config --base-libs
zerkms@ubuntu-1204-2-server-amd64:~$ gnustep-config --objc-flags
```

and after executing `GNUstep.sh` there are a lot of `GNUSTEP_*` environment variables added:

```
GNUSTEP_IS_FLATTENED=yes
GNUSTEP_LOCAL_ROOT=/usr/Local
GNUSTEP_HOST=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/zerkms/GNUstep/Library/Libraries:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib
GUILE_LOAD_PATH=/home/zerkms/GNUstep/Library/Libraries/Guile:/usr/local/lib/GNUstep/Libraries/Guile:/usr/lib/GNUstep/Libraries/Guile
GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES=/usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles
GNUSTEP_NETWORK_ROOT=/usr/Network
GNUSTEP_FLATTENED=yes
GNUSTEP_HOST_OS=linux-gnu
GNUSTEP_HOST_VENDOR=pc
PATH=/home/zerkms/GNUstep/Tools:/home/zerkms/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
GNUSTEP_HOST_CPU=x86_64
GNUSTEP_USER_ROOT=/home/zerkms/GNUstep
GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_ROOT=/usr/System
GNUSTEP_PATHLIST=/usr/System:/usr/Network:/usr/Local:/home/zerkms/GNUstep
CLASSPATH=/home/zerkms/GNUstep/Library/Libraries/Java:/usr/local/lib/GNUstep/Libraries/Java:/usr/lib/GNUstep/Libraries/Java
INFOPATH=/usr/share/info::/usr/local/share/info::/home/zerkms/GNUstep/Library/Documentation/info:
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing your installation did you include the `GNUstep.sh` script into your environment first?

For example:

```
. /usr/local/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh
```

#### References

- [3.1 Installing the Core Libraries](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/User/GNUstep/gnustep-howto_3.html)
- [4. Additional Installation](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/User/GNUstep/gnustep-howto_4.html)

Comment: I did (see PPS in the question). I even restarted the server

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. After reading code, I found out that make isn't installed
Please check that you have installed make

```
# apt-get install make
```